# HTML5 and CSS3 show form hints on element focus

Tags: html, css

I am building a website in HTML5 and CSS3, I am looking to create form hints for form fields that show the the field has `:focus` I would like to do this without javascript is this possible, below is my form markup.

```
<label for="username">Username</label>  
<input type="text" name="username" value=""/>
<div class="message">You need a username that is more than 5 letters long</div>
```

Is it possible to show `.message` when the username input has `:focus` using just psuedo classes in CSS3?

Comment: I see no HTML5 or CSS3 in your code.

Comment: Add `id="username"` to your input, otherwise `label for="username"` will not work as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, since you mentioned CSS3 here's a solution with some CSS3 fade in/out flair.

**HTML**

```
<label for="username">Username</label>  
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<div class="msg">You need a username that is more than 5 letters long</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.msg { color:#999; opacity:0; display:inline;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
input:focus+.msg { opacity:1; }
```

#### Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/RqaV6](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/RqaV6/)

Answer (score 5):

Is this something you were looking for?

```
.message{visibility:hidden;}
input:focus+.message{visibility:visible}
```

edit:
You can also check this out:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector

Comment: … and this is only CSS 2 so it isn't bleeding edge.

Comment: +1 visibility is a good option too, if you want to reserve the empty space for the div.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        #message {display: none;}
        #test:focus + #message {display: block;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input id="test" name="test"/>
    <div id="message">message!!!</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```